# The basic idea of Handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am currently learning handlebar.js and I am a very beginner too.I have tried out simple handlebar exercise But I am not getting output as desired can anyone help out what mistake I have in my code.I am sharing my html and javascrpit code and I have downloaded handlebar.js 3.0 version to do this excercise.

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>   
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Handlebars.js Example Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="menu-placeholder"></div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <script id="menu-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">


            <ul>
            <li><a href="{{linkURL1}}">{{linkName1}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{linkURL2}}">{{linkName2}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{linkURL3}}">{{linkName3}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{linkURL4}}">{{linkName4}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{linkURL5}}">{{linkName5}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" /></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

my javascript file

```
var menuData = {
    linkName1 : "Link 1",
    linkName2 : "Link 2",
    linkName3 : "Link 3",
    linkName4 : "Link 4",
    linkName5 : "Link 5",
    linkURL1 : "http://google.com",
    linkURL2 : "http://jaskokoyn.com",
    linkURL3 : "http://yahoo.com",
    linkURL4 : "http://youtube.com",
    linkURL5 : "http://twitter.com"
};


// Grab the HTML source that needs to be compiled
var menuSource = document.getElementById( 'menu-template' ).innerHTML;
// Compiles the source
var menuTemplate = Handlebars.compile( menuSource );



// Process Template with Data
document.getElementById( 'menu-placeholder' ).innerHTML = menuTemplate( menuData );
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFytR93-PDc . you can follow this.

Comment: It seems same approach .But when I run my code in console the error is printed like handlebar is not defined

Comment: Check your console for a load error or other issue.

Comment: can you post the console error ?

Comment: I have found the error.That is the naming error of handlebar